# Prevent error: "NotAuthenticated: Strategy jwt is not permitted"

Tags: error-handling, socket.io, jwt, feathersjs

I have FeathersJS as API Rest server with SocketIo. For authentication I use a Firebase and I send the fbToken from client, check it on server and authenticate accordingly. This is build on JWT model. 
All works well, except when I restart the server. While I did caught the `socket.on("reconnect_attempt", ()=>{... authentication function...}` and it works, I still got the error just before the re-authentication:

```
error: NotAuthenticated: Strategy jwt is not permitted
    at new NotAuthenticated (...my-path...\back-end\node_modules\@feathersjs\errors\lib\index.js:93:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (...my-path...\back-end\node_modules\@feathersjs\authentication\lib\hooks\authenticate.js:31:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (...my-path...\kludi\back-end\node_modules\feathers-hooks-common\lib\common\iff-else.js:17:63)
    at ...my-path...\back-end\node_modules\feathers-hooks-common\node_modules\@feathersjs\commons\lib\hooks.js:164:73
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
```

Questions:

1. Why do I get the error? Indeed JWT is not registered, I named the method "firebaseAuth" but who is calling the auth function with JWT strategy? Could not find in the code.
2. Should I ignore it or address it? I don't feel comfortable leaving an error not fixed, even if it does no harm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem so if anybody else is reaching this posts:

Make sure your new configuration is ***before*** the initialization of socketIo, otherwise it will attempt to use the JWT.
In my case that is:

```
restApi.configure(auth(
        {
            header    : 'Authorization', // the default authorization header for REST
            prefix    : '', // if set will add a prefix to the header value. for example if prefix was 'JWT' then the header would be 'Authorization: JWT eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOi...'
            path      : '/..........', // the server-side authentication service path
            strategy  : 'firebase_strategy', // the name of the JWT authentication strategy
            entity    : 'users', // the entity you are authenticating (ie. a users)
            service   : 'users', // the service to look up the entity
            cookie    : 'token', // the name of the cookie to parse the JWT from when cookies are enabled server side
            storageKey: 'token', // the key to store the accessToken in localstorage or AsyncStorage on React Native
            storage   : localStorage // Passing a WebStorage-compatible object to enable automatic storage on the client.
        }
    ));
```

And `const socket = io(...` follow after. Problem solved.